# Динамический urlManager Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток уважаемые знатоки.
Интересует такая схема:

Есть один модуль **main**, в нем несколько контроллеров (допустим

```
[
'masterHomeController',
'masterRepairController',
'courierOrdersController'
                        ])
```

Каждый из них имеет свои action (действия) - действия у контроллеров повторяются по названию, но не все.

**Какова моя задача?**
Загрузить модуль main по url `yii.local/main`
И в **независимости от контроллера** выполнять action с url такого вида

```
[
'yii.local/main/index',
'yii.local/main/active,
'yii.local/main/issued'
                       ]
```

Где main это модуль, index -> действия в контроллере.

**Какой контроллер?**

При загрузке модуля, при инициализации устанавливается значение defaultRoute (контроллера по умолчанию) - роль юзера.

Например: если заходит юзер с ролью masterHome.
При инициализации создается свойство defaultRoute со значением masterRepair(по сути master-repair)

Получается что контроллер по умолчанию. masterRepairController

**Какова цель обращения сюда?**

В представлении создаются ссылки типа `yii.local/main/active`, но они не работают. Так как нужно обращаться прямо на контроллер. так `yii.local/main/master-repair/active`

**Вопрос:**
Могу ли я создать динамический urlManager который обработает запрос. Допустим `yii.local/main/active` а на самом деле это `yii.local/main/masterHome/active`, скроет название контроллера, когда название контроллера зависит от роли юзера.

Кому не сложно, напишите пример, ну или хотя бы что и куда. Я новичек

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Честно говоря в интернете очень много ссылок на данную тему:
[вот](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/url-manager-in-yiiframework-2-0/) 
или
[вот](http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-routing-urlmanager/) или
[еще](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md)
даже в [оф. доках](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Рекомендую почитать))

А в общем если говорить - то да, можно насоздавать абсолютно любые, какие душе угодно правила маршрутизации.
Для этого в конфиге в разделе `urlManager`настраиваются правила (`rules`)

как пример

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,

    'rules' => [
        '<action:(login|logout|methods)\/?>' => 'site/<action>',        
        '<controller:(feed|settings)\d*\w*>' => '<controller>/index',
        '<controller:(chat)>/<id:(chat)?\d+>' => '<controller>/view',                   
    ],
],
```

Допустим сайт у нас `test.ru`

`'<action:(login|logout|methods)\/?>' => 'site/<action>'` - если пользователь зайдет по `url` `test.ru/login` или `test.ru/logout` или `test.ru/methods` то он попадет в контроллер `site` с экшном login/logout/methods соответственно

`'<controller:(feed|settings)\d*\w*>' => '<controller>/index'` - если юзер зайдет по контроллеру `feed` или `settings` и после этих контроллеров будут любые символы, то попадет в индексовый экшн этого контроллера

`'<controller:(chat)>/<id:(chat)?\d+>' => '<controller>/view'` - если юзер вобьет `test.ru/chat666` - то попадет в контроллер `chat` с экшном `view`

Для модуля это будет в том же духе.
У вас примерно:

```
'<module:(main)>/<action:(active)>'=>'<module>/master-home/<action>',
'<module:(main)>/<action:(index)>'=>'<module>/master-repair/<action>',
'<module:(main)>/<action:(issued)>'=>'<module>/courier-orders/<action>',
```

Не ручаюсь за правильность. Но почитав немного про маршрутизацию, думаю, вы с легкостью допишите правила под себя.

Если у контроллеров могут быть одинаковые экшны, то в таком случае придется дописать свой вспомогательный компонент, перемаршрутизатор так сказать, 
который будет смотреть какой надо контроллер использовать и уже у него будет вызывать данный экшн. 
Схематично:

```
if ($currentController == "masterHome") { 
    /master-home/action 
} elseif ($currentController == "masterReair") { 
    /master-repair/action 
}
```

и т.д.

А `urlmanager` будет использоваться лишь для скрытия контроллера.

Как вариант использовать класс правил..
Если смотреть в сторону создания классов правил, как написано [ТУТ](http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-runtime-routing.html)

Смысл в нем такой, что мы реализуем метод `parseRequest` сами ручками, который будет вычислять по какому правилу и как должен парситься `url`, а в `createUrl`, соответственно по каким правилам создаваться урл.

В принципе, если посмотреть бегло, то можно заметить, что смысл его будет ровно такой же, как я написал выше: зная какой контроллер нужно сейчас включить направлять экшн именно в него.

Т.е. в конфиге подключаем наш кастомный класс, чтоб он работал:

```
'rules' => [    
    [
        'class' => 'app\components\MyCustomUrlRule',         
    ],
    '<action:(login|logout|methods)\/?>' => 'site/<action>',        
],
```

Компонент схематично будет выгляить так:

```
    namespace app\components;
    use yii\web\UrlRuleInterface;
    use yii\base\Object;

    class MyCustomUrlRule extends Object implements UrlRuleInterface {

        public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params) {
            /* SiteModel::getCurrentController() -> надо реализовать метод в модели, который возвращает имя нужного применяемого в данный момент контроллера */
            $myCurrentController = SiteModel::getCurrentController(); 

            if ($route === 'main/index') {
                return 'main/'.$myCurrentController.'/index';       
            } elseif ($route === 'main/active') {
                return 'main/'.$myCurrentController.'/active';      
            } elseif ($route === 'main/issued') {
                return 'main/'.$myCurrentController.'/issued';      
            }

            return false;  // данное правило не применимо
        }


        public function parseRequest($manager, $request) {
            $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();

                        /* SiteModel::getCurrentController() -> надо реализовать метод в модели, 
который возвращает имя нужного применяемого в данный момент контроллера */

            $myCurrentController = SiteModel::getCurrentController(); 


            if (preg_match('%^main/(\w+)?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) 
                return ['main/'.$myCurrentController.'/'.$matches[1]]

            return false;  // данное правило не применимо
        }
    }
```

P.S. [Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHxMwW8h9yA) По `urlmanager`. Там в конце тоже есть кастомный класс. Посмотрите, возможно почерпнете для себя идею лучше моей))

Comment: Это все верно, спасибо)
Но дело немного в другом.
Мне требуется подключить в url manager rule переменную, которая будет содержать название контроллера (это и есть роль юзера)
По этому и заголовок такой "Динамическое подключение"

Comment: Вы все верно написали, но если у меня несколько контроллеров и в каждом присутствует actionIndex, при загрузке он поймает первый пункт в urlmanager'e с названием контроллера к примеру "masterRepairController", но по сути он будет являться CourierOrder роли.

Comment: @Mr.Music ясно. Я что-то просто не увидел, что у вас могут быть одинаковые экшны (хотя об этом сам думал), поэтому и написал так. Пока вариант в голове - перенаправлять на какой-либо вспомогательный контроллер->экшн или компонент, который будет смотреть какой надо контроллер использовать и уже у него будет вызывать данный экшн. Типа `if ($currentController == "masterHome") { /master-home/action } elseif ($currentController == "masterReair") { /master-repair/action }` и т.д. А `urlmanager` будет использоваться лишь для скрытия контроллера.

Comment: Вот что я нашел. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.url
8. Использование своего класса правила URL
только это для первого yii

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#adding-rules как это реализовать? не очень понимаю

Comment: @Mr.Music Обновил ответ. Попробовал описать это там. Но суть этого класса будет всё такая же. Придется знать какой применять контроллер, чтобы его динамически впихнуть

Comment: $myCurrentController я просто заменяю своей переменной userRole (это и есть название моего контроллера , который используется в данный момент по умолчанию).
Спасибо!