# Yii 2 urlManager

Tags: php, yii2

Как можно настроить urlManager, чтобы ссылка `http://advanced1/category/ua1-1` обрабатывалась actionIndex,  притом последний параметр "ua1-1" может быть какой угодно например: ua1-2, ua1231, items …

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я вам рекомендую немного почитать об `urlManager` непосредственно в доках. Там все хорошо объясняется:
[вот](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/url-manager-in-yiiframework-2-0/) 
или
[вот](http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-routing-urlmanager/) или
[еще](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md)
даже в [оф. доках](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Об этом я писал и затрагивал в [данной теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468917/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-urlmanager-yii2/468936#468936) на ruSO. Тоже советую взглянуть.

А вкратце, в `urlManager` описываются правила в массиве как ключ -> значение. И вы там можете описать всё всё, что вашей душе угодно. Пример:
`'posts' => 'post/index'` - соответствие URL `post` маршруту `post/index`

А значит мы можем написать даже такой бред: `'user/index' => 'bread/bake'` - зайдя по URL решив посмотреть пользователя на самом деле обратимся к контроллеру Bread и методу Bake.

То есть, чтобы теперь со страницы `category/ua1-1` уходил в `index` можно написать:

```
'urlManager'=>[
            ...
            'rules' => [               
                'category/<id>' => 'category/index'
            ],
            ...         
        ],
```

При этом `<id>` можно описать регулярным выражением, если это требуется.

Как пример: `<id:\d+>` - здесь id это только числа.

А также не стоит забывать в контроллере дополнить входной параметр:

```
public function actionIndex($id)
```

Comment: Спасибо, узнал много полезного