# Правильная реализация контролера

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Здравствуйте. Нужно реализовать такой контролер. Например есть каталог телефонов http://site.loc/phone при нажатии на конкретный телефон переходило на http://site.loc/phone/htc.  То есть есть контролер phone, но экшен контролера каждый раз разный но вьюшка одинакова, подставляется только содержимое

Comment: а зачем так сложно?

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен быть **НЕ**правильная реализация контролера....... Скажите что вы пытаетесь сделать? Что за костыле-велосипедный-баг?)

Comment: Возможно, им просто нужно сохранить url'ы пре переносе приложения на yii, суть вопроса же не в том, зачем, а в том как

Comment: @Daniel-664 ответить напрямую "как" - не всегда правильно, если само действие описанное в вопросе неправильное. Возможно лучше более детально описать суть проблемы и в итоге найдется более подходящее решение, нежели сажать огурцы на яблоневое дерево.....Лучше написать "Хочу попасть с одного материка на другой", а не "Как мне пройти по дну океана и не задохнуться"

Comment: В формулировке вопроса ошибка. Опишите лишь результат, который вы хотите получить. Не пытайтесь предлагать свои решения - в них содержится ошибка, ведь с их помощью вы уже не смогли получить желаемый результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала **НУЖНОЕ и ВАЖНОЕ** отступление:

Для правильной работы, вы можете настроить `urlManager` так, как вам необходимо.
Что это и как работать можно почитать об `urlManager` непосредственно в доках. Там все хорошо объясняется:
[вот](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/url-manager-in-yiiframework-2-0/) 
или
[вот](http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-routing-urlmanager/) или
[еще](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md)
даже в [оф. доках](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Вкратце информацию можно посмотреть открыв этот спойлер:

```html
Если  вкратце, в `urlManager` описываются правила в массиве как ключ -> значение. 
И вы там можете описать всё всё, что вашей душе угодно. 
Пример:
`'posts' => 'post/index'` - соответствие URL `post` маршруту `post/index`

А значит мы можем написать даже такой бред: `'user/index' => 'bread/bake'` -
 зайдя по URL решив посмотреть пользователя на самом деле обратимся 
к контроллеру Bread и методу Bake.

То есть, чтобы теперь со страницы `category/ua1-1` уходил в `index` можно написать:

'urlManager'=>[
    ...
    'rules' => [               
     'category/<id>' => 'category/index'
    ],
    ...   
],

При этом `<id>` можно описать регулярным выражением, если это требуется.
Как пример: `<id:\d+>` - здесь id это только числа.
А также не стоит забывать в контроллере дополнить входной параметр:

    public function actionIndex($id)
```

Описание взято с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487553/191482

---

Теперь, с учетом полученных знаний делаем и ваш случай:

Допустим есть контроллер `PhoneController`, метод `actionTest` и этот метод принимает 1 параметр.

В итоге в `urlManager`, в раздел `rules` нам надо написать маршрут

```
'urlManager'=>[
    ...
    'rules' => [               
        'phone/<name:\w+>' => 'phone/test',
    ],
    ...         
],
```

Все запросы на `mysite.ru/phone/MY_URL_PARAM_DATA` будут перенаправляться на `phone/test` и при этом передавать параметр с именем `name` массива `$_REQUEST`

Теперь контроллер:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

class PhoneController extends \yii\web\Controller {

    public function actionTest($name) {
        return $this->render('test', ['myUrlParam' => $name]);
    }
}
```

В контроллере с переменной можно делать все что угодно, подставлять для выбора из БД или удалить)) В данном случае пока просто отдаем во вью `test` переменную, которую мы приняли из Урла

**Прошу заметить!!!** что имя входного параметра контроллера должен называться также, как он называется в `urlManager`

Ну и представление:

```
Это view/phone/test
<br />
Мой параметр, переданный в урл: <?= $myUrlParam; ?>
```

Всё.

Если нужно еще параметр принять, то в `urlManager` дописать правило, например:

```
'phone/<name:\w+>/<another:\w+>' => 'phone/test',
```

и не забыть добавить в контроллер

```
public function actionTest($name, $another) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас будет каждый раз разный контроллер, то можно просто отдавать в render один шаблон. Но это не лучший способ, у вас что, будет HtcController, NokiaController и т.д?

Вам можно не создавать разные контроллеры, а использовать один контроллер, и при желании даже один action, но при этом корректно составить карту роутинга, на yii2 она реализуется в конфиге, в разделе

```
'urlManager' => [
     ...
     'rules' => [
     ...
     ]
],
```

В разделе rules указывать необходимые параметры, это так же можно сделать по-разному:
`'phone/htc' => 'phone/index'` - указывать один action обработчик для всех марок, в этом случае придется обновлять правила при добавлении новой марки

`'phone/<action>' => 'phone/<action>'` - указывать разные action, для разных телефонов

`'phone/<id:\d+>' => 'phone/index'` - можно вообще передавать id марки телефона параметром id

Главное сделать более абстрактно, чтобы в дальнейшем было меньше проблем с расширением приложения

Comment: C `type` тоже включите в пример... что типа `phone/<phoneTypePattern> => phone/index` чтоб можно было принимать в экшне марку телефона и по ней уже можно было например в базе что-то найти

Comment: Вот как раз такое мне и нужно. Только как это реализовать

Comment: @MykolaShkit Это всего лишь работа с `urlManager` и правильная маршрутизация.... у вас `yii` или `yii2`? Это (ГРУБО ГОВОРЯ) разные фреймворки..... и если `yii2` то какой шаблон? `baisc` или `advanced`?